# Pipe not executing + signal handling

Tags: c, shell, unix, pipe, system-calls

I am trying to implement a simple two stage pipe in a shell.

When I don't do the second fork and just do the rest of the implementation of the pipe in the parent, it works fine but I exit the shell. That's why I want to do the second fork so I don't exit the shell. But for some reason nothing happens with the above code. Can you help me figure out what may be going wrong? I have a feeling it doesn't wait for both my processes to finish before exiting but I could be wrong.

Comment: Can you post a compilable program?

Comment: I could email it to you. The way I see it there are two ways I could do this:
(1) Parent fork child, child fork another child
(2) Parent fork 2 child
When I tried (1) I had two wait calls (one in parent, one in child) and my program never stopped waiting. So I am trying (2) now - but the second fork is giving me issues...

Comment: I think this may also be a problem with wait & SIGCHLD - not sure what the problem is though

Answer (score 1):

Solution:  close `fd[0]` and `fd[1]` in the parent.

In the twin fork model, which you want, your parent process (the shell) is keeping its copy of `fd[1]` open.  With this open, the child `pid2` will never see EOF on its standard input fd.

Comments:

1. both children should close their pipe fds after dup2'ing
2. the code after `execvp`, both above and in your *pastie* suggests that you think that `execvp` will return control under ordinary circumstances.  It does not.  For this code, at most you probably want to follow the `execvp` with a `perror` and `exit`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! is it ok to only have one waitpid though? I was actually thinking that when the first child is finished executing waitpid thinks it doesn't have to wait anymore and so noone waits for the second child. is it better to have two waitpids?

Comment: @user1710707, you might repeatedly call waitpid(-1, ...) until you get ECHLD.